# Finding radius of convergence for this power summation $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \left(\int_0^n \frac{\sin^2t}{\sqrt[3]{t^7+1}} dt\right) x^n$

Tags: calculus

I have been given this tough power summation that its' general $c_n$ has an integral.
I am asked to find the radius of convergence $R$

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \left(\int_0^n \frac{\sin^2t}{\sqrt[3]{t^7+1}} \, dt\right) x^n $$

Do I first calculate the integral?

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: You do not first *evaluate* (hopeless task). You *estimate*. There will be an easy upper bound. You will also want a not too bad lower bound.

Comment: Well I can say that the integral converges. Does that help me in any way?

Comment: And the upper bound I got is $\frac{1}{t^{\frac{7}{3}}}$

Comment: Certainly the integral exists, it is the integral of a continuous function on a bounded interval. Perhaps you mean that the integral to $\infty$ converges. That is true too, so your integral to $n$ is less than a constant. That shows the radius of convergence of the series is $\le 1$. The harder part is to show it is not $\lt 1$. For that you need a lower bound which is non-zero. That should be easy!

Comment: Why is it less than a constant? and why does that mean $\leq 1$?

Comment: Let $f(x)$ be the function you are integrating, and let $c_n$ be the integral. Then $c_n\lt B$ for some $B$. Thus if $|x|\lt 1$, you have absolute convergence, by comparison with $\sum B|x|^n$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

we have

$$\left|\frac{\sin^2t}{\sqrt[3]{t^7+1}}\right|\leq \frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{t^7+1}}\sim_\infty t^{-7/3}$$
and since  $\frac{7}{3}>1$ then the improper integral
$$\int_0^\infty\frac{\sin^2t}{\sqrt[3]{t^7+1}}dt$$
is convergent and the value of the integral is $\ell\neq 0$  so if we denote by
$$a_n=\int_0^n\frac{\sin^2t}{\sqrt[3]{t^7+1}}dt$$
then by ratio test we have
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\right|=1$$
hence we have
$$R=1$$

Comment: I understand and I got to the point where it is convergent.  But why does that ratio test give $1$? how did you calculate it? I mean I understand (and solved by myself) that it is convergent and even got the upper bound the same as yours. But why is  it $1$?

Comment: Is it because it has SOME value $l$ (because it is convergent) then the limit of $a_{n+1}$ fraction $a_n$ is 1?

Comment: the sequence $(a_n)$ is convergent to the improper integral and it's value $\ell$ different to $0$ so $\lim_{n\to\infty}\left|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\right|=\frac{\ell}{\ell}=1$

Answer (score 1):

We show that the radius of convergence is $1$.

Let $f(x)=\frac{\sin^2 x}{\sqrt[3]{x^7+1}}$. The integral $\int_0^\infty f(x)\,dx$ converges. Suppose it has value $B$.

Let $a_n =\int_0^n f(x)\,dx$. Then $a_n \lt B$ for all $n$.

By comparison with the series $\sum B|x|^n$, the series $\sum a_n |x|^n$ converges whenever $|x|\lt 1$. So the radius of convergence of our series is $\ge 1$.

We complete the solution by showing that the radius of convergence is $\le 1$. 
Note that $a_n \gt \int_0^1 f(x)\,dx$. Let $b$ be the value of this integral. Note that $b$ is positive.

If $|x|\gt 1$, then $b|x|^n\to\infty$ as $n\to\infty$. So $a_n|x|^n\to\infty$ as $n\to\infty$. It follows that if $|x|\gt 1$, then $\sum a_n x^n$ diverges.